# io.vertx.sqlclient.ClosedConnectionException: Failed to read any response from the server, the underlying connection may have been lost unexpectedly

Tags: vert.x

I'm using quarkus-reactive-mysql-client with Quarkus 3.5.1 ( io.vertx:vertx-mysql-client:jar:4.4.6) and sometimes I observe "io.vertx.sqlclient.ClosedConnectionException: Failed to read any response from the server, the underlying connection may have been lost unexpectedly." error, but it's not reproducible. I'm using read replica of Aurora DB 8.0.mysql_aurora.3.02.0 (compatible with MySQL 8.0.23). Any ideas what can affect in my case?

I've also tried to change idle-timeout and didn't help.

Comment: In my case it turned out is was an issue on Aurora DB side (a software issue in Aurora Storage driver component), engine version is needed to be upgraded to version 3.04.1